# UWP Background Application not deploying (Error DEP0700)

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I made a new solution, added two UWP Class Libraries, and a UWP Background Application (from this [template package](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MicrosoftIoT.WindowsIoTCoreProjectTemplatesforVS15)). I'm trying to debug locally and develop the app on my PC before deploying to a Raspberry Pi as I'm still waiting for the RPi delivery. However, when trying to build and deploy the project, I get the following error:

> DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF6]
>   AppxManifest.xml(27,6): error 0x80080204: Cannot register the
>   SHVending.Entry-uwp_1.0.0.0_x86__nn0daenrxbv52 package because the
>   following error was encountered while registering the App activatable
>   class: The Appx package's manifest is invalid. .  Try again and
>   contact the package publisher if the problem persists.

I have set the entry point in the app manifest to "SHVending.Entry.StartupTask" (which is the namespace + the startup class). I have also tried just "StartupTask".

If I leave the entry point blank, it *seems* to build and deploy properly, but then I get the following issue instead

[Unable to activate Windows Store App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d4Bv.png).

I'm building in Debug mode targeting x86 CPU on my Local Machine.

Edit: Just to clarify, the reason it's running on x86 is because Raspberry Pi only support x86.

Comment: It is an x86 dll that needs to be restistered.  See : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/249873/how-to-use-the-regsvr32-tool-and-troubleshoot-regsvr32-error-messages

Comment: @jdweng which dll needs to be registered? The "SHVending.Entry-uwp.dll" in the "bin/x86/Debug/Appx" folder? I tried registering that dll now but I get the [following error](https://i.imgur.com/V8EVHCq.png)

Comment: Check with vendor to see if it is compatible with Windows 10.  Not all x86 applications will run on windows 10.  If you have source you may need to recompile.  How old is the application?  You may be having issues with ActiveX components which were obsoleted in 2004.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What Vendor? This is a brand new UWP Background Application that I made today.

Comment: If it is new, Then why is it x86?  Are you using any dlls from other projects?   Was Net Library recently upgraded?

Comment: It's x86 because Raspberry Pi only supports x86.

Comment: It looks like a dll you are using is not Window 10 compatible. What libraries (dlls) do you have in the references?

Comment: I'm not referencing anything yet, it's empty C# UWP apps

Comment: Open up Solution Explorer and check the reference tab.

Comment: It's only referencing Universal Windows and Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform

Comment: Do you have Net Core SDK installed? : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/get-started?tabs=windows.  What libraries are referenced in the module on top (the using statements)?

Comment: Yes I have the Net Core SDK installed. I'm only referencing standard libraries (System libraries), the only non-standard one is `Windows.ApplicationModel.Background`

Comment: Should that be in the reference list?  Try from menu : Project : Add Reference then browse to the dll.  Windows is Framework so maybe you have to add Framework?

Comment: Everything needed should be included in the NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform

Comment: Why?  You need to have everything compatible with Core, but no reason you can't add other libraries.  The error you are getting for the Windows Store App is a "Group Policy" which means you do not have the privilege to access the folder/file.  You should be able to use Windows Explorer and use same path.  The path is in the csproj  (read with notepad) or right click the property in the Solution Explorer Reference.

Comment: I just created an empty UWP app in C++ to see if it works, but it's the exact same thing - it complains about the Group Policy.

Comment: Group Policy is used in Corporate Networks to create user groups which allow/deny access to folders/files.  The must be something in the csproj file that is accessing a remote folder.  Open the csproj file with notepad and see what is in the file.

Comment: The only external reference is `<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" />`

Comment: You need to check the environmental variables for MSBuildExtensionPath and VisualStudioVersion.  These are either defined in the csproj or from an environmental variable.  You can open cmd.exe and type >Set to get all the definitions.  It also may be in the config file.  If they are not defined that could be the cause of the problem.  They would be a empty string and the Group Policy is saying the path doesn't exist.  You could temporarily edit the file and put hard locations of the target.

Comment: @SchalkvanderMerwe. You may try to clean the solution and then build and deploy again. BTW, if you try to build and deploy for Raspberry Pi, you need to select ARM platform.

Comment: @SchalkvanderMerwe. You may try to clean the solution and then build and deploy again. BTW, if you try to build and deploy for Raspberry Pi, you need to select ARM platform.

Comment: @SchalkvanderMerwe Did you fix this? I'm having the same issue with the template.